Grails 5 DeepDomainClassMarshaller JSON failing for Circular reference and for null values
Hey folks i am trying to use Grails JSON feature for generating json from a domain class.
And i am facing many issues in this one after another.
If someone can help me here it would be great. I have following grails configuration
grailsVersion=5.3.2
grailsGradlePluginVersion=5.3.0
groovyVersion=3.0.11
gorm.version=7.3.3

I have following 3 domain classes.
Company.groovy
class Company{

    String name

    String contactName

    String agentId // If businessType = Accountant
    String status  = "Active"


    User owner
    User lastUpdatedBy


    static hasMany = [apps: ZApp]
  
}


User.groovy
class User {

    Long id

    String fullName
    String username
    User owner
    User lastUpdatedBy
}

And ** ZApp.groovy**
class ZApp{

    String appName

    String appDescription
}

I have added following line in my application.groovy file for deep domain marshaller.
grails.converters.json.default.deep = true
And than i tried to generate json for company instance as following
company as JSON
I am getting following error
Caused by: org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: start 0, end -1, length 0
When i check error trails it giving me error in JSON.java file in following line

I thought this should handle it automatically gracefully. but no, than i adding following line in application.groovy
grails.converters.json.circular.reference.behaviour='PATH'
And error solved but now error comes whenever any field has null value. In my case agentId of company class is null
Caused by: org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: org.grails.web.json.JSONException: Value out of sequence: expected mode to be OBJECT or ARRAY
when writing 'org.grails.web.json.JSONWriter$NullWritable@1a1fd03d' but was INIT
Error coming at following code from DomainClassMarshaller.java
if ( !(property instanceof Association) ) {
                // Write non-relation property
                Object val = beanWrapper.getPropertyValue(property.getName());
                json.convertAnother(val); // **here it throws error**
            }

To By pass this error i created my own CustomDomainMarshaller class and in place of
json.convertAnother(val); i used
if (val == null) {
   writer.value(null)
} else {
   json.convertAnother(val);
}

And it worked.
But now i got another error for apps (Hasmany relation for ZApp)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.grails.web.json.PathCapturingJSONWriterWrapper$PropertyElement cannot be cast to class org.grails.web.json.PathCapturingJSONWriterWrapper$IndexElement (org.grails.web.json.PathCapturingJSONWriterWrapper$PropertyElement and org.grails.web.json.PathCapturingJSONWriterWrapper$IndexElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
This error is coming when we have 2 item in apps. and when call second item.
Error is coming in following code.
    @SuppressWarnings(["unchecked", "rawtypes"])
    public void marshalObject(Object value, JSON json) throws ConverterException {
        JSONWriter writer = json.getWriter();
        value = proxyHandler.unwrapIfProxy(value);
        Class<?> clazz = value.getClass();

        List<String> excludes = json.getExcludes(clazz);
        List<String> includes = json.getIncludes(clazz);
        IncludeExcludeSupport<String> includeExcludeSupport = new IncludeExcludeSupport<String>();

        BeanWrapper beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(value);

        writer.object(); // **here it throws error**

And in postmen following json response coming.
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 72050630615,
            "lastUpdatedBy": {
                "id": 59396476865
            },
            "dateCreated": "2024-03-30 18:07:42",
            "contactName": "Chetan",
            "lastUpdated": "2024-05-22 18:54:21",
            "agentId": null,
            "apps": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "appName": "ZUCODU MTD SERVICES",
                    "appDescription": "Use this app to file you tax using Zucodu MTD app"
                }{
                    "message": "Internal server error",
                    "error": 500
                }


you can simply @JsonIgnoreProperties( 'owner', 'lastUpdatedBy' ) on User class to avoid the circular dependency

The problem is that your User references itself, which may cause a looping. The hasMany relationship also is problematic because Grails always messes this up somehow.
We had similar problems and we opted for not using JSON parses directly on domain classes. Instead, we started using DTO classes, parsing data to a "non-artifact" class. It's a best practice and avoid Grails unexpected behaviors.
I know it doesn't solve what you trying to do, but I think it's worth considering.
